# Compile C++ code containing OpenMP with manually built gcc compiler

Tags: gcc, openmp

I've downloaded from github and built gcc. After that I've tried to compile a code with OpenMP:

```
../GCC/build/gcc/xgcc -B./../GCC/build/gcc/ -I./../GCC/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgomp -Wno-write-strings -O3 -Wall -fopenmp -lpng -o mandelbrot-omp mandelbrot-omp.cpp​
```

Then I got the following error message:

> xgcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory​

I've checked and found out that `libgomp` directory contains the `libgomp.spec` file. The directory is included with `-I` option. What's wrong?

Comment: Try to add the directory where the file is located with `-L` option: `-L./../GCC/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgomp`. Does it work if you copy `libgomp.spec` to `/usr/lib` and use your current command?

Comment: I've tried both ways. Still get the error.